# Plain text automated email encoding

Tags: php, email, plaintext, dashcode

Have made an automated plaintext email in php to be sent to the user upon registration. However, the sign off includes an en dash. I have tried &ndash ; &# 8211; and &# x2013; (without spaces) but none of those are working and just showing the code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the unicode equivalent for your dash, must be something like \u2013 or such, you cannot use html entitites since you are not using html ...